# Relation between Faculty, Student and Course tables

Tags: mysql, sqlite

What should be the relation between following tables. Confuse whether i create an enroll table with **student** and **course** or courses_assigned table using **faculty** and **course** and then create an enroll table with a foreign key of courses_assigned table.

This model is for an educational institute system, where users are students and faculty members. Courses are assigned to faculty members and students are enrolled in courses.

System will show courses and their instructors(faculty members) to each student which he or she has to study and faculty members will see record of all students of a particular section which he or she has to teach.

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide the requirements for how the system is intended to work?

Comment: A data model encodes the rules from the domain being analysed. Without knowing the rules it is impossible for us to say whether the model is correct. If you edit the question to include some rules we may be able to help. One technique to verify a model is to see if it can satisfy the types of queries the system will eventually submit.

Comment: Question updated. I hope, it is clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One Course can have many Sections.  "One-to-many".  That is handled via a `course_id` column in the `Sections` table.

Many Students take many Courses.  "Many-to-many".  That is handled by a many:many table with two columns: `course_id` and `section_id`.  Note that you can find the `course_id` from the `Sections` table.

Facilty:Sections is also many:many.

I don't know where you are going with "OneToOneField".  Generally it is not good to have two tables in a one-to-one relationship.

`Students` and `Facilty`, though both humans (I guess), do not seem to be related at all.  Well, maybe you have "student teachers"?

Comment: Why do you think that Sections are unique? It is possible that Course-Section relation is many-to-many too...